# How to make UIScrollView inside a UIScrollView act simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm using a UIScrollView (**UIScrollView_1**) with paging enabled to move between 3 pages horizontally.
On the last page there is multiple UIScrollViews (each one in its own cell) (**UIScrollView_2**), which when scrolling horizontally to the right (forward) displays the last page (loaded accordingly to which cell that was scrolled).
But if scrolling in the left direction (backwards) I want the UIScrollView_1 to take over and scroll back.
This works as intended if I move my finger up and register a new touch-event. But I want it to act simultaneously between both the UIScrollViews, on the same pan.

```
|-------------UIScrollView_1----------|    
| Page_1 | Page_2 |--UIScrollView_2---|  
..................|...Page_3|Page_4...|
```

What I want is to make use of the shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith in the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate.
But when I trying to delegate both the UIScrollViews' to the same ViewController the error ***'UIScrollView's built-in pan gesture recognizer must have its scroll view as its delegate.'*** shows up on the ScrollView_2.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

**UPDATE**

Here's the cellForRow from page_3's UIViewController that not causing the error with the delegation, but where the UIScrollViews doesn't act simultaneously. (e.g need to move the finger up and down to detect the other UIScrollView.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "random", for: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

Here's the cellForRow that causing the ***'UIScrollView's built-in pan gesture recognizer must have its scroll view as its delegate.'-error***

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "random", for: indexPath)

    let scrollView_1_VC = self.parent
    cell.scrollView_2.panGestureRecognizer.delegate = scrollView_1_VC

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.
The `UIScrollView`'s built-in `UIPanGestureRecognizer` must be delegated to its own `UIScrollView` as the error ***'UIScrollView's built-in pan gesture recognizer must have its scroll view as its delegate.'*** said.
Instead subclass the `UIScrollView` and create a second `UIPanGestureRecognizer` which then acts simultaneously with the built-in `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

**Step 1 - 4:**

1. Subclass the cell's `UIScrollView` and create a second `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.
2. Add the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to the `CellScrollView` and make the `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith` return `true`.
   The second `UIPanGestureRecognizer`  will now act simultaneously with the built-in `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

```
class CellScrollView : UIScrollView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {   
    var panGesture : UIPanGestureRecognizer!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: nil)
        addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
     }
    
     func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

3. In the cellForRow, make the newly created UIPanGestureRecognizer delegate to the UIScrollView_1's UIViewController.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {        
    if medicines.isEmpty {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "emptyMedCell", for: indexPath)
    }
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "random", for: indexPath)
    let scrollView_1_VC = self.parent
    cell.cellScrollView.panGesture.delegate = scrollView_1_VC
    return cell
}
```

4. Lastly, in the ScrollView_1's UIViewController let the shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith return true.

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use something like

```
func gestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if page3 {
        return true
    }
}
```

On the UIViewController of ScrollView_2 and have the ScrollView_2's(not the gesture's) delegate as the ViewController,

```
ScrollView_2.delegate = self
UIPanGesture.delegate = ScrollView_2
```

Comment: Yes, thats what I'm trying. But when I delegating the UIScrollView_2's UIPanGestureRecognizer to the UIViewController that error 'UIScrollView's built-in pan gesture recognizer must have its scroll view as its delegate.' appears and the app crashes.
Without the delegation the shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer won't notice the ScrollView_2.

Comment: I don't understand your example. I updated my question with the delegation function. Can you please use my code in your example instead?

Comment: @alengqvist sorry I can't figure out what you are trying to do in your code so I can't help you any further